# from neigbourhood base to base, countability

Tags: general-topology

We can go from bases $B$ to neighbourhood bases $B_x= \{U \in B| x \in U\} $

1) Given a neighbourhood base, is it possible to construct out of it a base for the topology? Assuming the neighbourhood base is countable under which conditions is it also the base of the topology?

2) If we say $(X,\tau)$ is separable so there is a dense countable subset, under which conditions is the base of the topology also countable (completely separable) ?

3) Its said that neighbourhood bases are also filter base. Can one can make out of filter bases also a base for the topology. Or how is the relation between the topology and filters?

Answer (score 0):

A space in which each point has a countable  local base is called a First-Countable space. A space with a countable base is called a Second-Countable space. The simplest example of a 1st-countable space that's not 2nd-countable is the discrete topology on an uncountable set  $X$: For each $x\in X$ the set  $C_x=\{\{x\}\}$ is a local base at $x,$ but if $B$ is a base then the uncountable set $\{C_x:x\in B\}$ must be a subset of $B.$

There are many examples of 1st-countable separable spaces that are not 2nd-countable. E.g. the Sorgenfrey Line (a.k.a. the lower-limit topology on $\Bbb R$) and the Niemitzky plane (a.k.a. the Moore plane or the Moore-Niemitzky plane). Also, a space can be separable but not 1st-countable (and hence, a fortiori, not 2nd-countable). And there are even spaces that are countable (and hence separable) but not 2nd-countable.

On the other hand, metric spaces are 1st-countable. And a metric space is 2nd-countable iff it is separable.

Comment: To 2) Is it the only case to get equivalence between A2 and separable, like does this only hold under a pseudometric, or is there a weaker condition than pseudometric? , for 1) i wonder if one could identify conditions to connect these terms more, that would exclude the mentioned counterexamples.